# Where can I buy Magic: The Gathering cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are there web sites where I can buy cards from Magic: The Gathering? I want to buy the Exalted Darkness and Dream Puppets decks from the Xbox 360 version of Magic: The Gathering 2013.

Comment: A quick Google search for "buy individual magic cards" reveals many sites.

Comment: The OP was looking for those decks already boxed up. I know the answer is probably that you can't get them like that, but the edit does change the intent.

Comment: One of the earliest versions of DotP did also bring along paper versions of some of the decks, but I'm guessing it probably didn't sell ver well and so was discontinued.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because requests for off-site resources attract open-ended lists of opinion-based links prone to link rot.

Comment: Also, it's practically inviting spam and similar advertisements.  Forgot that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy Magic: The Gathering cards at [TCGPlayer.com](http://www.tcgplayer.com/) and [StarCityGames.com](http://www.starcitygames.com/), just to name a couple. Some vendors offer free shipping if you purchase more than a minimum threshold.

The decks from inside the game are not sold in real life as a complete bundle. You'll have to hand select the cards yourself. Here are the decklists you mentioned, for reference:

- [Exalted Darkness](http://www.ign.com/wikis/magic-the-gathering-duels-of-the-planeswalkers/Exalted_Darkness_(White_and_Black))
- [Dream Puppets](http://www.ign.com/wikis/magic-the-gathering-duels-of-the-planeswalkers/Dream_Puppets_(Blue))