# Ways to find and purchase out-of-print / rare / old supplies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My question came from missing out on finding a copy of the [Ajani v. Nicol Bolas Duel Deck box](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CHI7FQ) to complete my set of duel decks.

When something goes out of print, it obviously becomes harder to find. What resources are available to find items when amazon or ebay have none listed anymore? I've tried a dozen other online shops with similar aspects to them, as well as my local game stores (in Seattle, so I'm not lacking any). I've also checked google's shopping section, as well as the top 5 pages of most of the possible variations I could come up with. If you can find one I would love a link to a shop with one in stock, but I'm more interested in the method of finding items - how would one go about finding other rarities, like the christmas special MTG cards? If it's not on amazon, what is the next step?

Thankyou for your time ~

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I buy Magic: The Gathering cards?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18894/where-can-i-buy-magic-the-gathering-cards)

Comment: @Rainbolt I had seen that question, but I thought it was enough of a departure in that the linked one was a simple question about just finding singles, where I had intended to mean it as a question more along the lines of 'how to find things that are not listed on the normal popular websites / what steps would you go through as a collector searching for x item.' For example, if someone were looking for misprints, they could be linked to the misprint Facebook page. If you or other people still think that it's a duplicate I'll defer to you all and close it though.

Comment: That was an example meant to differentiate my question from the linked one - like misprints, certain supplies or items can be hard to come by, and that one does not cover items not listed on the more... tertiary level websites? Not sure the phrasing. themisprintguy on reddit and the misprint page on Facebook cover misprints, high end magic on facebook covers black lotuses, I just mean to ask where to go for that one rare deck box or play mat uou can't live without - ideally, something like a reverse ebay would be great hah

Comment: Whoops, I deleted my comment because I wanted to edit it but I ran out of time. Anyway, I think the question needs to be more targeted. Are you looking for misprints? Ask that. Are you looking for  holiday promos? Ask that. Both of those questions are useful. "Where can I find anything and everything that is rare?" is so broad. I mean, do you ever get on eBay and search for "rare stuff"? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something like this that you can't easily find through most normal sellers I would try contacting the Customer Service departments of larger sellers like [Star City Games](http://starcitygames.com) or [Channel Fireball](http://channelfireball.com) and see if they have any way of finding the item in question for you. I don't know if CFB does this, but [SCG](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/market-street/market-street-cafe/store-discussion/388586-starcitygames-discussion-thread?comment=812) does have a process for managing user requests, they might not have it in stock now, but knowing that you are interested in buying one means they are likely to acquire one if they come across a seller.

Comment: Oh! I had no idea, that's fantastic. I had checked them both out, but had no success finding the item. I'm still looking for other methods in general so I can have a bit more of an idea in general how people go about finding rare things, but I'll right up an email to SCG right away. Thanks!